# What's a real-world example of using StringBuffer?

Tags: java, string

I'm using Java 6.

I've only written a couple of multi-threaded applications so I've never encountered a time when I had several threads accessing the same StringBuffer.

Could somebody give me a real world example when StringBuffer might be useful?

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry I think I wasn't clear enough. I always use StringBuilder because in my applications, only one thread accesses the string at a time. So I was wondering what kind of scenario would require multiple threads to access StringBuffer at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only real world example I can think of is if you are targetting Java versions befere 1.5. The [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class was introduced in 1.5 so for older versions you have to use [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead.

In most other cases `StringBuilder` should be prefered to `StringBuffer` for performance reasons - the extra thread safety provided by `StringBuffer` is rarely required. I can't think of any obvious situations where a `StringBuffer` would make more sense. Perhaps there are some, but I can't think of one right now.

In fact it seems that even the Java library authors admit that `StringBuffer` was a [mistake](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6304514):

> Evaluation by the libraries team:

> It is by design that StringBuffer and StringBuilder share no
> common public supertype.  They are not intended to be alternatives:
> one is a mistake (StringBuffer), and the other (StringBuilder)
> is its replacement.

If `StringBuilder` had been added to the library first `StringBuffer` would probably never have been added. If you are in the situation that multiple threads appending to the same string seems like a good idea you can easily get thread safety  by synchronizing access to a `StringBuilder`. There's no need for a whole extra class and all the confusion it causes.

It also might be worth noting that the .NET base class library which is heavily inspired by Java's libraries has a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class but no `StringBuffer` and I've never seen anyone complaining about that.

Answer (score 2):

A simple case cane be when you are having a Log file and multiple threads are logging errors or warnings and writing to that log file.

Comment: (This SO ? was refed from a Linked In thread recently.) 
I was going to use this as an example also, but there are very few situations where using a "Basic type" or similar directly from the Java library to represent a logical function in code has been a good idea for me. There always comes a time, sooner rather than later, when you need to add a feature to it or need to differentiate (by compiler/IDE) between the logical feature and the same type used for something else. Dedicated classes for auto-inc DB index, is too much work but not really an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In general, these types of buffered string objects are useful when you are dynamically building strings.  They attempt to minimize the amount of memory allocation and deallocation that is created when you continually append strings of a fixed size together.

So a real world example, imagine you are manually building HTML for a page, where you do roughly 100 string appends.  If you did this with immutable strings, the JAVA virtual machine would do quite a bit of memory allocation and deallocation where with a StringBuffer it would do far less.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer is a very popular choice with programmers.

It has the advantage over standard String objects, in that it is not an immutable object. Therefore, if a value is appended to the StringBuffer, a new object is not created (as it would be with String), but simply appended to the end.

This gives StringBuffers (under certain situations that cannot be compensated by the compiler) a performance advantage.

I tend to use StringBuffers anywhere that I dynamically add data to a string output, such as a log file writer, or other file generation.

The other alternative is StringBuilder. However, this is not thread-safe, as was designed not to be to offer even better performance in single-threaded applications. Apart from method signatures containing the sychronized keyword in StringBuffer, the classes are almost identical.

StringBuilder is recommended over StringBuffer in single threaded applications however, due to the performance gains (or if you look at it the other way around, due to the performance overheads of StringBuffer).

Comment: I think it should be "StringBuffer WAS a very popular choice with programmers", until StringBuilder was introduced :)